# Simple Parallel Computation Achieves Better Results When Having More Threads Than Cores

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a simple Java application that basically increments a counter 600M times. I have separated this task into several threads, each incrementing its own counter, and finally summing these counters.
Oddly, having more threads than cores achieves better performance:

Example (on **Intel I7-9850H** with six cores) for average calculation time:

- Having 6 threads, each with 100M increments yields **97 ms**
- Having 60 threads, each with 10M increments yields **61 ms**

AFAIK Java maps each thread to a real system thread.
**Any ideas why is this happening?**

**EDIT**:
Is it possible that the reason is that my computer has many other running processes and threads, so competition of 60 threads against all other inhabits is better than having only 6 threads competing on CPU resources?

The code of the increment method:

```
private static void incrementWithLockFree(long increments, int threads) throws InterruptedException {
    final long[] numbers = new long[threads];
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    for (int task = 0; task < threads; task++) {
      int finalTask = task;
      threadPool.submit(() -> {
        for (long increment = 0; increment < increments; increment++) {
          numbers[finalTask]++;
        }
      });
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
    threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    long number = 0;
    for (long num : numbers) {
      number += num;
    }
    System.out.println(number);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system less threads perform better.

> Is it possible that the reason is that my computer has many other running processes and threads, so competition of 60 threads against all other inhabits is better than having only 6 threads competing on CPU resources?

Yes.

In case this is a real use-case, take a look at [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html), which is optimized for multithreaded counter scenarios.